# What's the point in AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID?

Tags: android, widget

```
public class WidgetConfigure extends Activity {

private int widgetID;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.widget_configure);
    widgetID = this.getIntent().getExtras().getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, new Intent().putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widgetID));
}
```

}

I think it's useless to know that your widget configuration activity got wrong widget id. Should I inform the user: "Hey there is a little problem, please try again." That is so lame, this should never happen, is it even possible to happen, to receive wrong widget id? If anyone knows meaningful use of `AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID` please let me know :).

Answer (score 0):

`AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID` is used to determine, if you were successfull retrieving  the id of your widget.

As an example:

```
widgetId = this.getIntent().getExtras().getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);

if(widgetId == AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID){
// something went wrong
}
else{
// proceed...
}
```

You have to pass in two arguments into `getInt()`. If retrieving the Id of the `AppWidget` fails, then `getInt()` will return the second argument (the default value). And since `AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID` can never be the actual Id of an `AppWidget` it is safe to check it like demonstrated above. (Btw you could also just compare it with 0, since [the value of `AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID` is 0](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/9f03d4f921fab5757a791653891ce73c2d006e20/core/java/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager.java#L244).)

Comment: I was not asking how to know activity received bad widgetID, but what is the best way for the application to behave in this situation.